# Setting a default date format on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good afternoon,

Many of you may already know that it is possible, for instance, in Oracle set the default date format used by formatting functions (ie to_char), just like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='SYYYY/MM/DD~HH24:Mi:SS'
```

My question is: is there any equivalence for this on PostgreSQL. I have been searching for an answer without success although I have found some references to the PostgreSQL locale settings (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/charset.html). Anyhow, I have been unable to figure out an answer.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance and best wishes for this holidays!

Comment: Are you really using version 7.4? That's EOL for a long time... Use a newer version, at least version 8.3 at this moment, all older versions are EOL. And use the matching documentation.

Comment: Actually I am working with 10g but the code I am working with was written ages ago. What I am doing is migrating that code to PostgreSQL, so the question arised. Anyway, your suggestion is a good reminder for all of us. Thanks!

Comment: check my edited answer, this will fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-formatting.html) doesn't have a default format, but you could use a variable for this to overcome this issue.

Just create your own to_char function, using a default setting:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_char(timestamptz) RETURNS text AS
$$
    SELECT to_char($1,'YYYY/MM/DD~HH24:Mi:SS'); -- here your default setting
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The "normal" to_char function will also work, you still have that option.

Comment: Looking good!That's the most accurate way to proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

It's possibly that `SET DATESTYLE` does what you want, at least for day, month, year portions of the date.

Search [here for DateStyle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: That will only give you 4 fixed options, not a user defined one.