# How do I import dataset with inconsistent date style in Postgresql (pgAdmin4)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a dataset with inconsistent data type in date column as follows:

```
order_date
04/30/19 09:27
2004-12-19  2:38:00 PM
```

I wanted to import this dataset to my localhost Postgresql by creating a temporary table with same columns and datatypes.

There was a data type error in order_date column. I tried changing the data type to text so that I can correct the inconsistency problem with SQL query after importing the dataset.

Import succeeded but the date values changed from the original one:

```
04/30/19 09:27
04/12/19 14:38
```

It seems like Postgresql changed the original `yyyy-mm-dd...` into `mm/dd/yy` date style. I cannot do anything about this dataset because I cannot even import it with correct date data to SQL. (The dataset is about 200Mbytes, CSV file)

I would like to know how I can import a dataset with inconsistent date style like above to Postgresql localhost database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a default date format on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616075/setting-a-default-date-format-on-postgresql), and you could import that field to a VARCHAR(), and then write some script to convert them to a correct datetime.

Comment: `date` columns do **not** have "a format". Any format you see is applied by your SQL client when _displaying_ the values

Comment: @luuk I did that too. Same thing happened. All date changed to the latter one. Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks but why the original date values change after importing them with text type? I want to know how I can import them with original date values.

Answer (score 0):

Typical ETL challenge where you have to Transform some input (aka garbage) into something useful. You basically need these steps, where step 3 is the most important and time consuming part:

1. Create a table with only text-fields for all the fields of your input
2. [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) the input to this table
3. Validate the data in this table and update the records and columns with consistent and correct data
4. Insert the transformed data into your target table
5. Empty (or drop) the table that you created at step 1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but after copying the input to the text-fields table from CSV file (After step 2) I see the same problem. Date style changed to the latter one like shown above which is incorrect value. Is this Postgresql problem? Am I (a poor beginner) is missing something? arggg...

Comment: Show me. I cannot believe that PostgreSQL will change a text field, so you have to convince me ;-) Check this Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e2398229592fc9555771ed9990fed4bf

Comment: !!!! I didn't know I had to use INSERT, and UPDATE in step 2, inserting individual value manually. The dataset has more than 186000 rows, and this means I have to INSERT and UPDATE approximately 93000 times?! (half of the values in the date column has yyyy-mm-dd... and the other half has mm/dd/yy...) What if I have a bigger dataset? It's gonna take my life to do all. :) Is there a better way to handle this problem? I really really thank you for helping me with this problem!!!

Comment: You can use COPY as well, it's just a way to get the original data in a TEXT field. And afterwards you have to look for patterns and update all records that match a pattern. You're not going to do that by hand for each record.

Comment: !!!! I used COPY and Postgresql changed the value! The code I wrote as follows:
Step 1: 
    CREATE TABLE csv_tbl(
    id TEXT,
    product TEXT,
    ...
    order_date TEXT
);

Step 2:

COPY csv_tbl(......., order_date)
FROM '....\data.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Checking after COPY:

SELECT *
FROM csv_tbl

Result:

.....order_date
     mm/dd/yy hh:....
     mm/dd/yy hh:...(--> originally yyyy-mm-dd hh:....)

Comment: Could you please create an example where PostgreSQL changes your content? I see your text, but I can't test it in for example dbfiddle.

Comment: I only see an online Postgresql database where I cannot import or COPY from CSV FILE. I think the problem arises when I import or COPY from a csv file, so I cannot find a way to show it to you. argggg.... I checked the manual input case, creating a table with a TEXT column that has two different date style values (INSERT). This has no problem at all. It stores values as they are. But, Postgresql constantly changes date values when I import or copy from a csv file with two different date styles to TEXT TYPE.

Comment: That would be a serious bug in PostgreSQL, changing TEXT content just because it smells like some sort of date. Please show us a real example where this happens and how we can check it ourselves.

Comment: I gave it a try using your examples and COPY, works fine, nothing changes. Show us your table definitions and lets find the bug.

Comment: Frank! I found it!!! hah hah. It took me almost 8 hours to find out what was going on! There is a bug reading csv I guess. In order for datetime values in text type to be copied as they are in original csv, I need to open it in microsoft excel and save once before copying to sql database (pgadmin4). This is really weird and I do not know why this is so at all. Here's the data I tested and please have a look if you want: https://www.kaggle.com/mithil1729/united-states-e-goods-sales
And, thanks a lot for helping me out, Frank! I learned a lot doing this and that to have this issue resolved. :)

Comment: Wait...what if a dataset I want to run in sql is over 3gbytes, which too big be open and saved in Excel... what should I do when the dataset has the same issue, two different datetime styles in a column...argggg.

Comment: Excel... The root cause of a lot of headaches! Why do you have to open that CSV file in Excel anyway? When you're sure it's CSV, you can use COPY in any PostgreSQL client to upload the content to your database. Just make sure all columns for that table accept any garbage, so use TEXT datatype. And when that is done, start the cleansing and updates of the columns in the correct format.

Comment: The thing is, if I don't open the CSV file and save it once in EXCEL, postgresql keeps changing date values when copying or importing even with TEXT type. That's why I am saying it's really weird. If I just use COPY, the date values changes automatically like I said above. lol...

Comment: No, it doesn’t, it can’t. Unless you have created some triggers that change the content